# smtpclient.send() sends the email sussessfully even to wrong address(address that doesnt exists)

Tags: c#, smtpclient

i need to check if the mail is sent to specified user successfully
but this function returns no error for the email addresses that even doesnt exists

how to handle this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't handle this. The mail server only rejects addresses that it knows are incorrect. Any address that might exist has to be passed along to the recieving mail server that can determine if it knows what to do about it.

For any incorrect address you will normally get an error mail back to the sender address.

Comment: This behavior, incidentally, makes sense when you think about it.  If a spammer had a way of determining which email addresses were valid and which weren't, for instance, he could focus his annoying-ness much more effectively.

Answer (score 4):

Only server can know if the address is correct because the server really tries to send email to recipient. Client does not have any means to know that because it talks only to it's own server. That's why most of the sites use 2-step user registration:
1. User enters email and site sends confirmation to the address
2. User must click a link in the confirmation email to prove that email is correct. Only after that new user gets accepted.

Comment: About the two step verification: Yes, that is what I am doing, but do you mean that I cannot check if the email is really sent or not? (Do not worry, I am not attacking you, I can't really do it at the moment)

Answer (score 4):

in C# you can set DeliveryNotificationOptions to DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure
and if it's failure you will get an email in the sender inbox about the failure

Comment: `DeliveryNotificationOptions` causes an NDR to be sent to the `Return-Receipt-To` address, not the `SmtpClient` instance.